# Average in file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I have this code

```
def PromNotas():
    archivo = open ("archivo.csv","r")
    archivo2 = open ("archivo2.csv","w")
    for reg in archivo:
        reg = reg.strip("\n")
        datos = reg.split(",")
        prom = (datos[1] + datos[2])/2
        reg2 = datos[0] + "," + datos[1] + "," + datos[2] + "," + str(prom)
        if prom >= 7:
            reg2 = reg2 + "," + "Aprobado\n"
        else:
            reg2 = reg2 + "," + "Desprobado\n"
        archivo2.write(reg2)
    archivo.close()
    archivo2.close()
```

The csv file looks like this:

```
Matt,7,8
John,9,6
Jim,6,7
```

All the code works but the line of `prom = (datos[1] + datos[2])/2` it says that the list index is out of range. Does anyone know something.

Comment: please indent properly

Comment: Can you show us the content of the csv files that you are using?

Comment: sorry I did not realised of the indentation on the question

Comment: [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and print `datos` and `reg` in the except suite.  Are they what you expected?  Are there any blank lines in your file? Do All lines in the file have two commas (`,`)?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains. If you are asking about code that throws an exception, please include the Traceback (formatted as code) in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Given the script and the input csv file the program runs correctly for me.
The only thing that I changed is casting the numbers to integers `prom = (int(datos[1]) + int(datos[2]))/2`

Make sure that you are using the correct input file and check that there aren't any empty lines or lines with less than 2 arguments on them.(2 commas)

Comment: You can try debugging it to see if you are getting the correct data in the variables. I cannot see any problem with this code snippet, I coppied it as it is and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the error and print `datos` and `reg` in the except suite. Are they what you expected? Are there any blank lines in your file? Do **all** lines in the file have three columns.?

```
...
    datos = reg.split(",")
    try:
        prom = (datos[1] + datos[2])/2
    except IndexError as e:
        print('datos:{} | reg:{}'.format(datos, reg))
        #raise

    reg2 = datos[0] + "," + datos[1] + "," + datos[2] + "," + str(prom)
...
```

Or, if you don't mind a lot of *stuff* printing, just print `reg` and `datos` just before the assignment to `prom`.  Then the last *print* before the exception should give you a clue to what is wrong.

```
...
    datos = reg.split(",")
    print('datos:{} | reg:{}'.format(datos, reg))
    prom = (datos[1] + datos[2])/2
...
```

When you split `reg` it must produce a list with less than three items so the file either has blank lines or lines with less than two *columns*.